# uicollection view datail view

Tags: cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I am new in iphone. I have a collection view in my app and it work fine but now I want to select an image and that image I want in next viewcontroller in another imageview. `- (NSInteger)collectionView:`

I use the following code:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return recipeImages.count;
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    // go on...
}
```